# What is the best approach of using django and ajax?

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm now working on my first big project and can't understand how to use Django with ajax.
On my website there are several services which works separately and are written on javascript, but soemtimes I have to send some information to the server.
Also I have custom admin interface which contains of different changing database operations. All these actions should be done without reloading the page (using ajax post and get requests).

**So, I think I have two ways of doing it:**

1. Using ajax and classic Django *views for each operation*.
2. Using ajax and integrated into my website *Django REST Framework API methods*.

The stumbling block is that I wouldn't use this API methods from any other types of clients, just call them from users' browsers via ajax. What is the best approach in my situation? It seems to me that the second way is more "serious", but I don't have much experience of making projects like this and can't speak directly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to integrate REST. You can do ajax call to normal view like you do with user interaction. The view can return http response or JSON or whatever you need. If you would like to change somethink in DOM without refreshing page I can sugest HTMX (https://htmx.org/)

standard ajax call to get some json:

```
let datas = {id: $(this).val(),};
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'to_your_view' %}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: datas,
                    success: function (json) {


                        console.log(json);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

and in view:

```
def to_your_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        id = request.POST.get('id', 0)
        if id != 0:
             return HttpResponse(json.dumps(100), content_type="application/json")
```